# jQuery animate scrolltop - prevent on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I am trying to create a scrolling effect with jQuery animate, but only for a keyboard user. I do not want the page to scroll for mouse users. Below is the current code. I am still having issues getting the click function to actually not scroll.

```
//scroll page with keyboard focus   
$(':focusable').on('focus', function() {
    var ele = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ele.offset().top - 100
    }, 500);
});
//do not scroll page with clicking of mouse
$(':focusable').on('click', function() {
    var ele = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop:  ele.offset().top - 0
    }, 5000);
});
```

The closest I have come is to change the animation time to 5 seconds and not add any height to the scroll distance as I did with the focus function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. Can't you just delete the second function that binds on click?

Comment: You'd have better to provide a jsFiddle. Why instead of `focus` event don't you try `keyup` event? And BTW, remove the click event. Indeed, not sure what you are expecting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your approach, A. Wolff. I removed the click all together and came up with this solution.

```
//scroll page with keyboard focus   
$(':focusable').on('keyup', function(e) {
     var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (keyCode == 9) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
           scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 100
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Thanks for the assistance.